# Match version numbers for graceful fallbacks - with Regex?

Tags: regex, versioning

My product has version numbers like major.minor.subminor. Various resources get templatized by the version, so that, say, 7.0.1 may define a message, and that may be used thru the 7.X line except for versions 7.2.3 and 7.2.8 which customize the message. 8.0.1 may then change the message.

I need to get the best matching version of the resources. That would be the last defined version if there was not an exact match, first by subminor, then by minor, then major.

I would think this is a fairly standard practice. Is this kind of a match best done (or even possible) with a regex, and if so, what would the regex be like? Or should I just go ahead and implement this algorithm?

Answer (score 1):

An example:
Django uses a list of regexpes to match incoming urls to views.

So a simple list of regexpes, where the first match is the one you want, and then you use it's data.

Your described list should look like this:

```
/^8/      "Message 4"
/^7.2.8/  "Message 3"
/^7.2.3/  "Message 2"
/^7/      "Message 1"
```

Comment: Wasn't that what you described. 7.2.3 should use message 2, but 7.2.4 shouldn't? Retrace your question. And am I solving the right problem?

Comment: Seems like you're describing building up a list of possible matches beforehand i.e. if only the major version matches, use Message 1. I'm trying to find the closest match at runtime without building up this list first. So, try to find an exact match down to the subminor; if not, look for a minor match which is the closest counting down. So if my version was 7.2.6, there is no exact match. Then see if there is a template for 7.2. If not, look for one defined for 7.0, if not, 6.0. And so on.

Comment: OK, a single regexp cannot do that. But why don't you do as you say and perform 3 searches? Should be pretty fast and easy to implement. You just described the algorithm you want to use, why don't you use it?

Comment: Does your response mean this needs multiple regexes, or that it cannot  be done with regexes? If I modify the problem statement to say I want to fall back on only the last digit, can yo suggest a regex that can work?

Comment: I say one regexp can't do it. Many can. As you described, use the following regexpes: /7.2.3/ /7.2/ /7/
If you do those searches, use the first match